# Background threads created are not killed by Android O

Tags: android, multithreading, background, android-8.0-oreo

While testing the background execution limits as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) I created a thread in my service. Something like this :

```
// spawn own thread
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("TestServiceThread");
thread.start();
```

The service is started by the usual pre Oreo `startService`.
What I noticed while debugging in android device monitor is that the threads I create continue to live long and healthy and execute normally. Can this be a workaround to keep abusing system resources and not do things via foreground services or jobs ? or is it just a chase against the framework which will soon end ? Any comments ?

Comment: Did you get any new/additional information on it? I am curious about this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect that to change.  Its impossible (not just in Android, its theoretically impossible) to safely kill a thread without the thread helping out.  Otherwise you could kill the thread in a condition where other threads will deadlock, have inconsistent data, or the app may just not function.  That's why thread.stop() is deprecated-  because there is no way to make it safe.  And that's why you interrupt a thread instead, and the thread needs to monitor isInterrupted and exit cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful with this kind of approach.

Although Gabe Sechan's answer is quite valid, the danger of relying on this working is too high to pursue this.  Google are clearly out to get any app that tries to do background execution and abuses the user's battery and for good reason in my opinion.  Some apps just don't respect a user's battery at all.

The documentation clearly states:

> An app is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following
>   is true:
>
> It has a visible activity, whether the activity is started or paused.
>   It has a foreground service. Another foreground app is connected to
>   the app, either by binding to one of its services or by making use of
>   one of its content providers. For example, the app is in the
>   foreground if another app binds to its: IME Wallpaper service
>   Notification listener Voice or text service If none of those
>   conditions is true, the app is considered to be in the background.

Source:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services

Although it's not safe to kill a thread due to all the reasons mentioned by Gabe, Android could well kill the app off entirely (ala kill -9).  I would imagine that any deadlocks would be handled by Android (not a trivial task I'm sure).  Data corruption would be considered as the app's fault for not handling background execution properly.

It's a bit of a risk for Android but they've probably weighed it up and decided this is the way to go.

Also, take care of this:

> Note: By default, these restrictions only apply to apps that target
>   Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher. However, users can enable most
>   of these restrictions for any app from the Settings screen, even if
>   the app targets an API level lower than 26.

Source: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#overview

Comment: I agree and so I moved background execution into on demand Android Jobs.